# Join 2 tables to find out how many open incidents a customer has open

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, duplicates

I'm doing a piece of work that has highlighted a number of accounts in our internal system that have been duplicated. To identify the duplicates, I've created the following script:

```
select SAMAccountName, COUNT(*)
from dbo.customer
group by SAMAccountName  
having COUNT(*) > 1
order by SAMAccountName asc
```

[image: duplicate accounts]

The `NULL` accounts need to be ignored as they are related to PowerShell scripts being used currently.

On the back of this, I need to find out how many open incidents these duplicates have on our system. This is where I have to dip into the Incident table. I'd like to bring back the following columns from Incident...

```
select customerdisplayname, customeremail, status
from dbo.incident
```

[image: Incident Table Fields]

The Status of the incident CANNOT be `Resolved` or `Closed`.

The `CustomerDisplayName` field in the Incident table is the same as `FullName` in the Customer table. Not sure if this will be needed in the script.

Any help you have on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Also please act on [mcve].

Comment: @LeeMac Please do not inline links inappropriately. See my comment above re using text whenever possible. Either replace a link to a table by code block formatted tabular text (which should simultaneously be code to create & initialize a table if the question should give a [mcve]) or, much better, comment to tell the poster to do it.

Comment: @philipxy I don't see that this is an inappropriate use of inline images; whilst I agree that text is always desirable over images of text, if the OP is not willing to oblige or others editing the post do not have the time to re-type the content of the images, the inline images make the question much more readable in the meantime.

Comment: As my comment re text says, I call it inappropriate because it's not following the edit guideline of editing all of a post, not just some--you are leaving it in a poor state because you did not textify the image. Also it is rewarding bad posting by the asker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, and assuming that duplicate `SAMAccountName` values could have differing `fullname` values, then the following seems appropriate:

```
select t.SAMAccountName, i.customerdisplayname, i.customeremail, i.status
from
(
    select SAMAccountName
    from dbo.customer
    group by SAMAccountName 
    having count(*) > 1
) t
inner join dbo.customer c on t.SAMAccountName = c.SAMAccountName
inner join dbo.incident i on c.fullname = i.customerdisplayname
where i.status <> 'Resolved' and i.status <> 'Closed'
```